# Devise gem sign in with facebook get " You are already signed in." after sign in or sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I have a sign in/ sign up for my app using the following gems

```
# Devise is a flexible authentication solution for Rails based on Warden. It:
gem 'devise'
#using omniauth
gem 'omniauth'
#facebook authentication using omniauth
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

But after the user sign-in or sign-up I always get the flash:

> You are already signed in.

This is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      super.tap do |user|
        if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
      end
    end
end
```

My User controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Any Idea or suggestion?

Comment: try to delete all users from the db and try again.

Comment: @RailsOuter I tried, but same error

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Solution is to change `after_sign_in_path_for` method. For example in `ApplicationController`:

`def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    super resource
  end`